# Width and Height of Sprite after Scaling in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I scaled the sprite to 70%  and I measured the width and height of the sprite. The size is reduced in the screen but when I checked the width and height using the getWidth() or with getRegionWidth() the width remains same.

Please assist me in get the width and height of the sprite after scaling

```
    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Before Scale");
    System.out.println("popUpSprite.getWidth() " + popUpSprite.getWidth());
    System.out.println("popUpSprite.getHeight() " + popUpSprite.getHeight());
    System.out.println("popUpSprite.getRegionWidth() " + popUpSprite.getRegionWidth());
    System.out.println("popUpSprite.getRegionHeight() " + popUpSprite.getRegionHeight()); 
    popUpSprite.setScale(.7f); 
    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!After Scale");
    System.out.println("popUpSprite.getWidth() " + popUpSprite.getWidth());
    System.out.println("popUpSprite.getHeight() " + popUpSprite.getHeight());
    System.out.println("popUpSprite.getRegionWidth() " + popUpSprite.getRegionWidth());
    System.out.println("popUpSprite.getRegionHeight() " + popUpSprite.getRegionHeight());
```

### Logcat

```
04-14 19:44:33.908: I/System.out(18918): !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Before Scale
04-14 19:44:33.908: I/System.out(18918): popUpSprite.getWidth() 1000.0
04-14 19:44:33.908: I/System.out(18918): popUpSprite.getHeight() 1400.0
04-14 19:44:33.908: I/System.out(18918): popUpSprite.getRegionWidth() 1000
04-14 19:44:33.908: I/System.out(18918): popUpSprite.getRegionHeight() 1400
04-14 19:44:33.908: I/System.out(18918): !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!    After Scale
04-14 19:44:33.908: I/System.out(18918): popUpSprite.getWidth() 1000.0
04-14 19:44:33.908: I/System.out(18918): popUpSprite.getHeight() 1400.0
04-14 19:44:33.908: I/System.out(18918): popUpSprite.getRegionWidth() 1000
04-14 19:44:33.908: I/System.out(18918): popUpSprite.getRegionHeight() 1400
```

Comment: setScale does not change width/height parameters. It's only information for render to scale current object while drawing

Comment: Any way to get width and height information for the scaled sprite

Comment: for example: popUpSprite.getWidth() * yourScale

Comment: Thanks Piotr Golinski